# JMS Serializer Event Subscriber Filters Out Proxy Classes

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have an entity `Acme\Bundle\Entity\Author` which has a one to many relationship to `Acme\Bundle\Entity\Article` and I have two JMS serializer event subscribers for both entities.

Subscriber for `Acme\Bundle\Entity\Author`;

```
acm.author_serialization_listener:
    class: Acm\Bundle\Listener\AuthorSerializationListener
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

---

```
class AuthorSerializationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return array(
                array('event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize', 'class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\Author' 'method' => 'onPreSerialize'),
            );
        }

    public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        if($event->getObject() instanceof Author) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Subscriber for `Acme\Bundle\Entity\Article`;

```
acm.article_serialization_listener:
    class: Acm\Bundle\Listener\ArticleSerializationListener
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

---

```
class ArticleSerializationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function getSubscribedEvents()
        {
            return array(
                array('event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize', 'class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\Article' 'method' => 'onPreSerialize'),
            );
        }

        public function onPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
        {
            if($event->getObject() instanceof Article) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs in the `onPreSerialize` function when serializing `Author` along with related `Article` s in the `ArticleSerializationListener` subscriber class where it injects **Proxies\__CG__\Acme\Bundle\Entity\Article** instead of **Acme\Bundle\Entity\Article** entities which lead to exclude the related `Article` entities. Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get_class` you should simply use the operator `instanceof` because the proxies inherit from the entities. You compare two strings.

```
if($event->getObject() instanceof \Acme\Bundle\Entity\Article) {
    return;
}
```

Sidenode: Also the operator `!===` does not exist.

Comment: Your soltion does not work at all, since the serializer does not even get those entities I need as it filers them out from the `class` filter in the `getSubscribedEvents` itself. I edited my question to be more clear for you.
Thanks for the syntax correction!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem?